# Exim script before queue

Tags: smtp, exim

I need to open exim relay to a list of ips in a mysql database.
I think if I can run a script before a email is queued, I can do that. Is there a way?
Mail Enable for windows has a similar solution called "SMTP Inbound Command Scripting".

Comment: Isn't better to open relay for authorized hosts despite of IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# configure
. . . . . 
hide mysql_servers = localhost/myoneandonlybase/login/pass
hostlist myfriends = ${lookup mysql{SELECT ipaddr FROM submitters}}
. . . . .
acl_smtp_connect   = acl_conn
acl_smtp_rcpt      = acl_rcpt
acl_smtp_data      = acl_data
. . . . .
begin acl
acl_conn:
accept  hosts           = +myfriends
. . . . .
acl_rcpt:
accept  hosts           = +myfriends
. . . . .
acl_data:
accept  hosts           = +myfriends
. . . . .
```

Comment: If the server is also used for normal incoming emails, that approach will effectively block those connections as well.

Answer (score 0):

The default exim configuration file already has a hostlist `relay_from_hosts` that you can easily populate with an SQL lookup and get the desired result:

```
hide mysql_servers        = localhost/myoneandonlybase/login/pass
hostlist relay_to_domains = ${lookup mysql{SELECT ipaddr FROM submitters}}
```

Nothing more than that is needed.